# Retrieving logs using filter is not working?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, filters, infura

web3 has been connected to Infura node, can send signed transactions but web3.eth.filter is not working(405 error)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can find an open [issue](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/13) in the Infura Git

> We're working on finding a solution to this which can provide the functionality createFilter/getLogs was providing in a way which is scalable and secure. This feature is "Stateful Transaction Support" and is tracked in this issue [#10](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/10)

Comment: You can polyfill this feature around your provider using provider-engine:
https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine

Answer (score 0):

INFURA returns 405 for unsupported methods, which include the filter methods. At the moment we don't support creating filters, which store state in the Ethereum client, for our public infrastructure. This may change in the future.

The list of supported methods is here: https://infura.io/docs/

-Maurycy, INFURA